# In how many ways can these 5 people get a job in the above-mentioned city companies?

Tags: combinatorics

Three guys and two girls want to get a job. There are 3 companies in the city where only men are needed, 2 companies where only women are needed and 2 companies where both men and women are needed. In how many ways can these 5 people get a job in the above-mentioned city companies?
How to calculate it by using combinatorial formulas?

Comment: The answer to this problem is 2000 ways.

Comment: Multiply the number of ways the three men could get a job at the five companies which hire men by the number of ways the two women could get a job at the four companies which hire women.